# Angular HttpClient missing response headers

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-httpclient

I am trying to get into angular lately.
I have a paginated request.

```js
const myParams = new HttpParams().set('page', page.toString()).set('size', size.toString());
this.http.get<HttpResponse<User[]>>('https://localhost:8443/user/', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
      params: myParams,
      observe: 'response'
    }).suscribe((response: HttpResponse<User[]>) => this.data = response.body);
```

The total count of elements in the DB is transfered to the Client in the `X-Total-Count` header. i tried to read it like that:

```js
.suscribe((response: HttpResponse<User[]>) => {
    this.data = response.body;
    this.totalCount = response.headers.get('X-Total-Count');
});
```

But this does not work. It turns out that response.headers only includes a subset of the real http-response-headers.

this is what the headers object looks like

```js
"headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
  }
```

I am sure that X-Total-Count has been sent. Firefox devtools show it. Could you please tell me how to include it into the response?

[image]

**UPDATE**

This question differs from the one that has been identified as a duplicate in the following way: I have not been asking about how to inspect the full httpResponse. I figured that out on my own. I have been asking about why the `headers` attribute of the Response is not complete.

Comment: I am sorry to inform you that this is not a replica of the post you have mentioned. As you can see, I have used the approach from the answer you have linked. `observe: 'response'`. My Problem is that `response.headers` does not contain **all** the headers that have been sent by the backend.

Comment: Sorry, you are right!

Answer (score 116, accepted):

CORS requests only expose 6 safelisted headers : `Cache-Control` `Content-Language`
`Content-Type` `Expires` `Last-Modified` & `Pragma`.

In order to access custom headers with a CORS request, the server has to explicitly whitelist them. This can be done by sending the response header: `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

For example: 
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Total-Count, X-Paging-PageSize`

[MDN Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

Comment: holy lord what a rathole i just crawled out of. thank you for this answer. if you're using flask CORS, just set the expose header options and you're golden

Comment: In my case I added this on the ASP.NET Core server side CORS policy setup

 services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
                builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .WithOrigins(origins)
                .WithExposedHeaders(new string[] { "X-Total-Count" })
                .AllowCredentials();
            }));

Comment: For those of you that are looking how to add thes headers to a (.NET 6) ASP.NET Web API: use .WithExposedHeaders("X-Total-Count") on the CORS policy.

Answer (score 25):

The headers in an HttpResponse object are lazy-loaded, so `headers` will appear to be empty until you force the values to be loaded. Try calling `response.headers.keys()` to see all available header names. By the way, this also forces all values to be loaded into the map `response.headers.headers`.

Comment: If you are not using CORS then this is the correct answer. If I could upvote more I would!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `withCredentials: true` to the http options object.

Answer (score 2):

As Tsvetan Ganev stated before, if this is CORS request you need to explicity expose required headers in `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header by name. To achieve this you need to configure your application server, for example in Spring while using `WebMvcConfigurer` you can expose headers like:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .exposedHeaders("X-Total-Count")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

Using this configuration, your browser, beyond 7 default headers:

- `Cache-Control`
- `Content-Language`
- `Content-Length`
- `Content-Type`
- `Expires`
- `Last-Modified`
- `Pragma`

Will expose `X-Total-Count` header for your application as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Postman was able to fetch the custom "Authorization" header, but Angular wasn't. I solved it by explicitly exposing the custom header

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    // vvv
    config.addExposedHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    // ^^^
    config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
    config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
    config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
    config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PATCH);
    config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
    config.setMaxAge(1800L);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Comment: Had the same issue with Angular. I could see them in the response header in the browser inspector, but Angular couldn't read them. Exposing the header on the server solved it. Thanks for the tip.