# How to get http headers from backend while passing http parameters to it in ASP.NET Core and Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am using Angular 15 and ASP.NET Core 5. I get the paged items from backend when the `pageSize` and `pageIndex` are passed as parameters to it.

The action method that receives `pageSize` and `pageIndex` parameters then sends the paged items as well as `totalCount` to frontend.

Here's that code:

```
[HttpGet("getPagedCommodities")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPagedCommodities([FromQuery] PagingParameters pagingParameters)
{
    try
    { 
        var commodities = await _repository.Commodity.GetAllCommoditiesAsync();
        var totalCount = commodities.Count();
                
        var pagedCommodities = await _repository.Commodity.GetPagedCommoditiesAsync(pagingParameters);
                
        Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(totalCount));                

        return Ok(pagedCommodities);
    }
    catch
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
    }
}
```

In the frontend, this is the method that gets the paged items:

```
getPagedCommodities(pageSize: number, pageNumber: number): Observable<CommodityForList[]> {
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('pageSize', pageSize);
    params = params.append('pageNumber', pageNumber);
    
    let httpOptions = {
      params: params
    };
    return this.http.get<CommodityForList[]>(this.baseUrl + '/getPagedCommodities/', httpOptions);
      
  }
```

How can I read the `totalCount` http header parameter sent from server?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**How to access the header parameters of an API-response**

I now integrated your code into my own Angular/ .NET project and eventually figured out a code that works:

**Backend: Startup.cs**

I had to add `X-Pagination` to the CORS policy, otherwise it would always be `undefined`. [Click here to read why this is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443706/angular-httpclient-missing-response-headers).

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .WithExposedHeaders("X-Pagination"); // I had to add this line
    });
});
```

**Backend: Controller-Method**

I had to change the input parameters from `PagingParameters pagingParameters` to `[FromQuery] int pageSize, [FromQuery] int pageNumber`:

```
[HttpGet("getPagedCommodities")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPagedCommodities([FromQuery] int pageSize, [FromQuery] int pageNumber)
{
    try
    { 
        var commodities = await _repository.Commodity.GetAllCommoditiesAsync();
        var totalCount = commodities.Count();
                
        var pagedCommodities = await _repository.Commodity.GetPagedCommoditiesAsync(pagingParameters);
                
        Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(totalCount));                

        return Ok(pagedCommodities);
    }
    catch
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
    }
}
```

**Frontend: Service-Method**

By adding `observe: 'response'`, access to `HttpResponse<YourJsonObject>` will be granted. You can then get your header-values via `response.headers.get("Header-Key")`.

I also had to change the way I assemble the `httpOptions` (which is the second parameter of `this.http.get`).

```
getPagedCommodities(pageSize: number, pageNumber: number): Observable<{commodities: CommodityForList[]; totalCount: number}> {

    const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()
                                .append('pageSize', pageSize)
                                .append('pageNumber', pageNumber);

    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/getPagedCommodities/`;

    return this.http.get<CommodityForList[]>(url, { observe: 'response', params })
        .pipe(
            map(response => {

            // Access 'total count' in header:
            const totalCount = response?.headers?.get('X-Pagination');
            const parsedTotalCount = +(totalCount ?? 0);

            return { commodities: response?.body ?? [],
                     totalCount: parsedTotalCount };
            })
        );
}
```

Eventually I was able to access the returned values as follows:

```
this.getPagedCommodities(0, 1).subscribe(
    res => {
        console.log('Commodities-Array:', res.commodities);
        console.log('Total count:', res.totalCount);
    }
);
```

Comment: I want to get pagedCommodities as observable in the Listcomponent : this.commoditiesForList$ = this.commoditiesService.getPagedCommodities(this.pageSize, this.pageIndex); where, commoditiesForList$!: Observable<CommodityForList[]>; and to get the totalCount as: this.commoditiesForList$.subscribe(res => this.length = res.totalCount). is it possible? and  how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I tried your suggestion in the ListComponent as follows: this.commoditiesService.getPagedCommodities(this.pageSize, this.pageIndex).subscribe(res =>{
      const totalCount = res?.headers?.get('X-Pagination'); // totalCount = undefined;
      const ptotal = +(totalCount ?? 0) // ptotal = 0;
      const cts = res?.body ?? []; // cts = [];   As you can see, the results are not satisfactory!

Comment: Also, I couldn't use the map in the service get method, because I was prompted with an error. So I used its body directly in the ListComponent.

Comment: I integrated your code into my own Angular / .Net project and I was eventually able to reproduce your issues and solve them. Can you try my new suggestion?

Comment: About your first question: What exactly is your need there? You would like to be able to subscribe to `totalCount` and `CommodityForList[]` separately?

Comment: Firstly, I am using commodities list as Observable to combine it with input search text to have dynamic search, therefore, I need to get Observable  commodities list from service method, secondly, because I am using mat-paginator,  I need totalCount to set the Length property of it.

Comment: I think in this thread you asked a clear question: "How can I read the totalCount http header parameter sent from server?" I think my detailed post answers this question and goes even further. Sadly, you didn't even try if my updated solution worked. I think if you don't know how to proceed from there, you should open a new stackoverflow-thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the setting `observe: 'response'` to the http get to observe the whole response and not just the body.

```js
this.http.get(myUrl, {
  observe: 'response',
  params
}).subscribe(response => console.log(response))
```

So now instead of getting the body, you now get the whole response where `headers` and `body` is a property of that response:

```js
{
  headers: {
    totalCount: 123
  },
  status: 200,
  body: {}
}
```