# Why I get only two headers in Angular using HttpClient?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to get all headers from the response to a post method:

```
this.http.post<User>(this.url, user, {
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'json',
      })
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
      });
}
```

earlier:

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/user/login';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

I followed most tutorials and stackoverflow answers, but I get only two headers:
Headers: {"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null}

When I tried with postman and curl everything works fine, that is I get all the headers, but not in Angular (I'm using version Angular CLI: 15.2.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one - [Angular HttpClient missing response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443706/angular-httpclient-missing-response-headers)

In your case seems that second answer might help you, about headers being lazy loaded